# Migrate Users, Permissions, Access, Groups and Content from 1.6 to 3.3.X

Tags: migration, joomla-3.3.x

I have to update a joomla installation from 1.6 to a new version, hopefully 3.3.X.  I have been fooling around with step-by-step upgrade process to move from version to version.  So far it hasn't been going well.

As an alternative I was thinking to simply do a fresh install of the new Joomla 3.3 version if there was some way to then migrate the content from the old 1.6 installation.

Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Installing the new versions of components and extensions would not be hard, but I would need to move all the users, groups, access levels, as well as all the articles and menus.  Of course the articles and menus would need to keep their access and locations correct for it all to work.  Also I don't want to have to re-setup all the users.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

**Try again a step by step migration:**

Make a Backup first and then try this:

1. Follow this instruction to Upgrade Joomla 1.6.x to Joomla 2.5.x - http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/upgrade-joomla-16-to-25/
2. Be sure every component, plugin, template is ready for Joomla 3.3
3. Deactivate the rememberme plugin.
4. Then go to Joomla! Update under Components Menu, then click the Options button
5. Change the Update Server Setting to Short Term Support and save
6. Then you see the newest Joomla Update and you can process the usual way.
7. Activate your rememberme plugin.

Comment: On the redmigrator website it says is works from upgrading from joomla 1.5.  My site is 1.6, will redmigrator still work?

Comment: All migrations is available for 1.5 - 2.5 or 3.0. - Quote from redmigrator page. I try it by myself!

Comment: i pretty sure it is made to migrate from 1.5 to 2.5 or 1.5 to 3.0.. Doesn't say anywhere that it supports migrating from 1.6.  Although it would be really cool if it did.

Comment: Oh my mistake. It's true redmigrator migrates from 1.5 to 2.5 or 3.x. My second advice is then the right answer. I edit my post. Sorry.

Comment: Joomla migration guides (and pretty much all joomla documentation) is pretty useless. I'm going the same path as the OP, i.e., banging head around trying _upgrade_ a 1.6 site to 3.x, and then figuring out the fact that these docs don't help, trying to migrate database only. And (not) to my surprise, there isn't any documentation for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to ensure you're running Joomla 1.6.5 which is the latest of the 1.6 series. 
Once done, go to **Extensions** (top menu) >> **Update** >> **Purge Cache** >> **Find Updates**.

Updating using the 1 click update feature as described above will automatically update your core database tables, core code and core extensions. So you don't need to worry about manually migrating users, permissions etc.

You may however need to install more up to date versions of 3rd party extensions and template you have installed as there are some fundamental API changes since Joomla 1.6

Hope this helps

Comment: This is part of the problem.  I was in Joomla 1.6.0, and I use an update package to get up-to-date with 1.6.5.  That seemed to work pretty well.  I have read that this is the way to update, when after I Purge Cache and click Find Updates, it says it cant find any updates...  So I am stuck.

Comment: In the Options, do what do you have the **Update server** set to? Long Term Support or Short Term Support?

Comment: Are you talking about the Options in the Extension Manager: Update page?  In these options it only gives me permission choices, nothing else.

Comment: Select "Short Term Support" in Components -> Joomla Update.